# auto seeking in mediaplayer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

if i have a video of 70 Seconds and i want to play it directly from 31 seconds to onwards how can i do that in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/304.html

```
player.URL = "URL to wmv"
player.Ctlcontrols.play()
player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 31
```